# Sensu check-log regex falsely passing

Tags: ruby, regex, sensu

I am trying to set up a sensu check-log check. Logs look similar to the following:

```
2015-09-22 06:05:44,710 DEBUG log output here
2015-09-22 06:05:44,712 ERROR more log output here
2015-09-22 06:05:44,713 ERROR even more log output here
2015-09-22 06:05:44,714 WARN so much log output
```

I am running the check manually to test as follows:

```
sudo -u sensu /path/to/ruby /path/to/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb -f /path/to/log.log -q '/.*ERROR.*/' -r
```

which when I run the regex here:

http://rubular.com/r/j1NO8RFY2p

it captures the two lines I want. However the manual check returns this:

```
CheckLog OK: 0 warnings, 0 criticals for pattern /.*ERROR.*/.
```

So I keep getting falsely passing checks. Failing to see what I am doing wrong here and documentation is fairly lacking with this particular plugin. And yes, there are errors in the log to capture. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
Working code:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/check-log
sudo -u sensu /path/to/ruby /path/to/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb -f /path/to/log.log -q '.*ERROR.*' -r
```

Comment: May be try something like this: [\s?[\w ]+\s]?ERROR \s?[\w ]+

Comment: CheckLog OK: 0 warnings, 0 criticals for pattern /[\s?[\w ]+\s]?ERROR \s?[\w ]+/.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script generates cache in /var/cache/log, it stores the number of bytes read, and seeks to that position, so every time to do the test, you need clean the folder first.

```
rm -rf /var/cache/check-log
```

then run the fix code

```
sudo -u sensu /path/to/ruby /path/to/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb -f /path/to/log.log -q '.*ERROR.*' -r

CheckLog CRITICAL: 0 warnings, 2 criticals for pattern .*ERROR.*.
2015-09-22 06:05:44,712 ERROR more log output here

2015-09-22 06:05:44,713 ERROR even more log output here
```

Refer: [check-log.rb](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/plugins/logging/check-log.rb#L9)

Comment: I got a error running that particular check. I even tries '/*ERROR.*/' and got back the same falsely passing. You can see the error here: https://gist.github.com/beardedeagle/8058203040acc921cf8e

Comment: I still see the `/` in the result, please make sure you didn't add it some else.

Comment: Completely removed and ran the command verbatim. Reading rubydocs it appears to be an exception that get raised for invalid regex: http://apidock.com/ruby/RegexpError

Comment: so. you were 99% right. I did need to delete the cache folder. However the regex should be '.*ERROR.*'

Comment: Thanks to point that, I did the test with `-q 'ERROR'` and `-q '.*ERROR.*'` , both are working, but when copy/paste, some typo, I have fixed.

Comment: Thanks, it is nice to fix this issue. I am currently using the similar sensu check scripts, such as disk, cpu, memory, etc. If you have any problems, let me know.